# Regularized Latent Semantic Indexing in R

Tags: r, optimization, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to implement the Regularized Latent Semantic Indexing (RLSI) algorithm on R.
The original paper can be found here:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/hangli/sigirfp372-wang.pdf

Below is my code.

Here, I generate a matrix D from two matrices U and V.  Each column of U correspond to a topic vector, and it is made to be sparse.  After that, I apply RLSI on the D matrix to see if I can factorize it into two matrices, one of which has sparse vectors like U.

However, the resulting U is far from being sparse.  Actually, every element of it is filled with numbers.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
library(magrittr)

# functions
updateU <- function(D,U,V){
    S <- V %*% t(V)
    R <- D %*% t(V)

    for(m in 1:M){
        u_m <- rep(0, K)

        u_previous <- u_m
        diff_u <- 100
        while(diff_u > 0.1){
            for(k in 1:K){
                w_mk <- R[m,k] - S[k,-k] %*% U[m,-k]
                in_hinge <- (abs(w_mk) - 0.5 * lambda_1)
                u_m[k] <- (ifelse(in_hinge > 0, in_hinge, 0) * ifelse(w_mk >= 0, 1, -1)) / S[k,k]
            }
            diff_u <- sum(u_m - u_previous)
            u_previous <- u_m
        }
        U[m,] <- u_m
    }
    return(U)
}

updateV <- function(D,U,V){
    Sigma <- solve(t(U) %*% U + lambda_2 * diag(K))
    Phi <- t(U) %*% D
    V <- Sigma %*% Phi
    return(V)
}


# Set constants
M <- 5000
N <- 1000
K <- 30
lambda_1 <- 1
lambda_2 <- 0.5


# Create D 
originalU <- c(rpois(50000, lambda = 10), rep(0, 100000)) %>% sample(., 150000) %>% matrix(., M, K)
originalV <- rpois(30000, lambda = 5) %>% sample(., 30000) %>% matrix(., K, N)
D <- originalU %*% originalV


# Initialize U and V
V <- matrix(rpois(30000, lambda = 5), K, N)
U <- matrix(0, M, K)


# Run RLSI (iterate 100 times for now)
for(t in 1:100){
    cat(t,":")
    U <- updateU(D,U,V)
    V <- updateV(D,U,V)
    loss <- sum((D - U %*% V) ^ 2)
    cat(loss, "\n")
}
```

Comment: Can you boild your problem down to a minimal working example?

Comment: Thanks, Roman.  I think this is as minimal as it gets, and it wasn't working...  I did, however, found a mistake in the code yesterday, which I've pointed out below.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. Each row in U has to be set to a zero vector each time updateU function is run.